# How to merge txt file with the same name from all subdirectories

Tags: files, scripting, merge

I have folders with a lot of files, Each folder has txt files of the same name, I want to merge all txt files from all subdirectories into a single folder.

**Example:**

```
/home/parent/Folder1 ===> txtfile1.txt, txtfile2.txt, txtfile3.txt
/home/parent/Folder2 ===> txtfile1.txt, txtfile2.txt, txtfile3.txt
/home/parent/Folder3 ===> txtfile1.txt, txtfile2.txt, txtfile3.txt
```

I want to merge all files with the same name into a different folder.

```
/home/parent/Merged ===> txtfile1.txt, txtfile2.txt, txtfile3.txt
```

Comment: Is the question not specific? i have read how to ask a good question and still doesn't understand what is wrong with my question, I have search all the web about it and doesn't get a satisfied answer before asking!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
mkdir "/home/parent/MERGED"
find "/home/parent/Folder1" -type f -name '*txt' -printf '%f\0' | 
xargs -0 -I FILENAME find "/home/parent" ! -path '/home/parent/MERGED/*' \
-type f -name FILENAME\
-exec sh -c 'cat "$1" >> "/home/parent/MERGED/$2"' sh {} FILENAME \;
```

What it does:

- create target directory
- scan FOLDER1  and print filenames (without path) followed by NUL as separator
- read in this list with `xargs`
- run `find` once per input name and scan `parent` for files with said name
- exclude the target directory from this search
- concatenate the resulting finds into a file in MERGED with the given name

Note: The data in the output files is not necessarily sorted by the names of FOLDER1, FOLDER2 etc. but by how `find` retrieves the files.

Note2: Absolute paths are a necessity for properly filtering the merged directory.

Comment: I'm getting this error when i try this   ==>   find: paths must precede expression: `sh'

Comment: This looks like a typo or a misplaced asterisk. Could you show the **exact** command as you typed it in? Do the files and/or directories have spaces in them?

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
cd /home/parent && mkdir -p Merged || exit
typeset -A files
for file (Folder*/*.txt(nN)) files[$file:t]+=$file$'\0'
for file (${(k)files}) cat -- ${(0)files[$file]} > Merged/$file
```

Note the `n` glob qualifier to apply a numeric sorting to the glob expansion so `Folder2` comes *before* `Folder10` and `txtfile1.txt` before `txtfile10.txt` for instance.

Note that hidden files are skipped. If you want them merged as well, add the `D` glob qualifier.